# Scaffolding in JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA like Visual Studio

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am newbie in IntelliJ IDE

in Visual Studio we can create scaffolding extensions something like Kendo UI Scaffolder.

Please look at the following images

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to know Can I create something like that in IntelliJ ?
I want to create a wizard for some actions and generate some codes or files.

I know that I can create template or live template but I dont like these I want 
to create a complete and complex wizard with more options (forms,controls,...) and ...

Can I have something like Visual studio in IntelliJ ???

Comment: Yes, you can write a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA that would have this kind of UI.

Comment: @yole  thank you, so you say that I should write a plugin for something like that, Can you guide me and introduce tutorial or any guide ? I want to know how I can achieve this purpose

Comment: You can find plugin development documentation here: http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/